# Iterate PHP array and check for duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays

I am still new to PHP and I am creating a PHP array that consists of a person and their vehicle.

Example:

```
Array
(
    "owner" => "Person A",
    "car" => "BMW"
),
Array
(
    "owner" => "Person B",
    "car" => "Mercedes"
),
Array
(
    "owner" => "Person B",
    "car" => "BMW"
),
Array
(
    "owner" => "Person A",
    "car" => "BMW"
),
Array
(
    "owner" => "Person A",
    "car" => "DODGE"
)
```

Question:

What would be the proper way to iterate through the array and flag the duplicate BMW vehicle for Person A?

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: since you don't tell us what you've tried... here, play around with this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question (although pretty vague), I think I know what you're after.

I have written a little bit of PHP code that loads all data into a temporary object. The script checks if an owner already owns a car, before appending this to the temporary array. You can then choose what to do with a duplicate entry.

**Note**: I have modified your initial array a little bit, to make this script work.

`

```
$data = (object) array
    (
    array (
        "owner" => "Person A",
        "car" => "BMW"
    ),
    array (
        "owner" => "Person B",
        "car" => "Mercedes"
    ),
    array (
        "owner" => "Person B",
        "car" => "BMW"
    ),
    array (
        "owner" => "Person A",
        "car" => "BMW"
    ),
    array (
        "owner" => "Person A",
        "car" => "DODGE"
    )

);

$temp = (object) array();
// loop over the object to list every person
foreach($data as $row){

    // check if person already exists in the temp array, if not add it
    if(!property_exists($temp, $row['owner'])){
      $temp->$row['owner'] = array();
    };

    // load the cars into the right persons array
    if(in_array($row['car'], $temp->$row['owner'])){
        // Duplicate car.. do something.
    } else {
      array_push($temp->$row['owner'], $row['car']);
    }

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($temp);
echo "</pre>";
```

`

Here is a live demo:
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/di0v-ugyr